# Insert html code in specific place with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, insert, append

My departure code is stocked in variable in jquery and i want edit this variable with jquery for insert some line  in specific  place look to The code that wishes to receive after editing with the jquery blockquote

> My departure code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label required">Specification n°1</label>
    <div id="products_specifications_0">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label required" for="products_specifications_0_reference">Reference</label>
            <input type="text" id="products_specifications_0_reference" name="products[specifications][0][reference]" required="required" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label required" for="products_specifications_0_price">Price</label>
            <input type="text" id="products_specifications_0_price" name="products[specifications][0][price]" required="required" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> The code that wishes to receive after editing with the jquery

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label required">Specification n°1</label>
    <div id="products_specifications_0">
        <div class="col-sm-5"><!-- INSERT THIS LINE -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label required" for="products_specifications_0_reference">Reference</label>
                <input type="text" id="products_specifications_0_reference" name="products[specifications][0][reference]" required="required" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div><!-- INSERT THIS LINE -->
        <div class="col-sm-5"><!-- INSERT THIS LINE -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label required" for="products_specifications_0_price">Price</label>
                <input type="text" id="products_specifications_0_price" name="products[specifications][0][price]" required="required" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div><!-- INSERT THIS LINE -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your departure code do add this lines

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label required">Specification n°1</label>
    <div id="products_specifications_0">
        <div class="myclass"><!-- ADD THIS LINE -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label required" for="products_specifications_0_reference">Reference</label>
                <input type="text" id="products_specifications_0_reference" name="products[specifications][0][reference]" required="required" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div><!-- ADD THIS LINE -->
        <div class="myclass"><!-- ADD THIS LINE -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label required" for="products_specifications_0_price">Price</label>
                <input type="text" id="products_specifications_0_price" name="products[specifications][0][price]" required="required" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div><!-- ADD THIS LINE -->
     <button id="change">Click to Change</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

note that i have added a button there because you don't have mentioned any event. then add this script...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#change").click(function(){
           $(".myclass").addClass('col-sm-5');
        });
});
```

i hope this works for you

Comment: you did not understand what I mean i want  insert la the line code
`<div class="myclass">`
and 
`</div>`
but no problem i found a nice solution with CSS
THK  YOU